# non-static method move(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

When i try to use the move i.e. Slide.move(1,0) i get the error:  non-static method move(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

This is my code at the moment, which i have no idea whats wrong.

```
    public void move(int row, int col) {
        char [][] temp= new char [cells.length][]; 
        for (int i= 0; i< cells.length; i++) {
            int destRow = (i+row)%cells.length;
            temp[destRow] = new char [cells[i].length];
            for (int j= 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                temp[destRow][(j+col)%cells[i].length] = cells[i][j];
            }
              cells= temp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Key is which line of code causes the compiler error to occur. I'm wondering if it's in the main method which you're not showing us.

Comment: Are you calling this method from the `main` method? If yes then to do so you must create a `static-reference` between both the `main-method` and this `method`.

Comment: Or main can create an instance of the class and call move on the instance.

Comment: It would help if you showed the "context", and also split this into two separate questions.

Comment: In short, you have to show us the code where `move` is called to get more info.

Comment: I've looked at other questions but don't really get the theory behind it. I've just started learning java programming in university this semester and a bit behind in some parts. Would you be able to point me somewhere that i could read a bit more on these things?

Comment: I can post all the code, but i don't have a main method yet. For this project i have to do it in order where Task one doesn't consist of a main method. Task 2 is the one where i make the main method..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says.

Your `move` method is not static. It requires an instance of an object to be called, e.g.:

```
Slide s = new Slide();
s.move(...);
```

You are calling it, as it says, from a static context, i.e. a place with no `this`, perhaps another static method or directly via `Slide.move(...)`. You will need to not do that.

These fail:

```
Slide.move(...); // error: move requires an instance

// and

class Slide {
    void move (...) { 
        ... 
    }
    static void method () {
        move(...); // error: method is static, there is no instance
    }
}
```

These do not fail:

```
Slide s = new Slide(); 
s.move(...);

// or

class Slide {
    void move (...) { 
        ... 
    }
    void method () {
        move(...);
    }
}

// or

class Slide {
    static void move (...) { 
        ... 
    }
    static void method () {
        move(...);
    }
}
```

So either call it from a non-static context, or make it a static method.

As for recommending somewhere to read more about these things (which you asked in a comment), try the official Java tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ (take a look at the "Learning the Java Language" trail (in particular: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

As for your output problems, since that's a separate question, you'd want to post a separate question for it.

Comment: I don't have any static methods in my code... I'll just edit the first post with all the code to show you...?

Comment: Then you are calling it as `Slide.move(...)`, as I also said. You need to read the linked tutorial.

Comment: I see your edit. You would need to clearly indicate the line that is causing that error for your edit to be useful, of course.

Comment: You may also wish to take a look at http://sscce.org/. It's totally OK to be a "noob" at programming; that's why we're here. We only ask that you don't be a "noob" at asking questions (you'll get better answers anyways).

Comment: Haha yea, still need to get use to the terms in programming to ask better questions. Will read it all up soon. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well that is because you defined the `move` method as a non-static method by saying `public void` to make it static you need to write `public static void` instead.

Also be aware that variable names are case sensitive, if you write `Slide.move()` you clearly call upon your `Slide class` because your variable was named `slide`.